# Why does SAS warn that these variables have never been referenced

Tags: sas

I am running a `SAS Script` that used to work.

When I run this part of the script

```
data PosteriorProbabilities (keep=Site VarStrg2(_,&MinGrp,&MaxGrp));
set TestOut;
run;
```

I get the following warning

> WARNING: The variable _1 in the DROP, KEEP, or RENAME list has never
>   been referenced.

The macro for VarStrg2 is below.

```
%macro VarStrg2(Pref,V_Beg,V_End) ;
%do n = &V_Beg %to &V_End ; &Pref&n %end ;
%mend VarStrg2 ;
```

I need this step to work so that the rest of the program can run. Any help or suggestions would be most welcome.

Comment: What columns does the dataset `TestOut` have in it? Is there one called `_1`?

Comment: Can you post the macro %VarStrg2?...and you should add the % sign to VarStrg2 your question.

Comment: Hi thanks for your comments. I checked the TestOut dataset and it has 22 columns and three of them are _1, _2, and _3. The table was created from a proc discrim script ROC DISCRIM data=Chem CrossValidate list method=normal TestData=Chem
                   canonical TestOut=TestOut outstat=discout;
  CLASS group;
  VAR %VarStrg1(,D,1,&Num_Chem);
  ID Site;
RUN;

Comment: Hi I was unable to edit my recent post it contains errors. I checked the TestOut dataset and it has 22 columns and three of them are 1, 2, and 3.  (note there is no underscore preceeding – and I am wondering if that could be the problem). The posterior probability dataset also has  columns labelled 1,2,3. I also adjusted the %varStr2 to include the %. I am still getting the same warning.

Answer (score 2):

The warning means that the variable _1 does not exist on the input data set.

I also assume you mean:

```
data PosteriorProbabilities (keep=Site %VarStrg2(_,&MinGrp,&MaxGrp));
set TestOut;
run;
```

With the `%` in front of `VarStrg2(...)`.